# Add column with variable value in previous group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have data, as below, where each `id` has a `status` at each `time`. I want to add a column `prev_status`, showing the value of `status` in the previous `time`.

```
set.seed(10); library(dplyr); library(data.table)

df <- data.table(time = sample(1:3, 20, T), 
                 status = sample(letters[1:15], 20, T)
      )[order(time)
      ][, id := 1:.N, by = time]

    time status id
 1:    1      j  1
 2:    1      g  2
 3:    1      k  3
 4:    1      m  4
 5:    1      d  5
 6:    1      c  6
 7:    1      m  7
 8:    1      o  8
 9:    2      m  1
10:    2      l  2
11:    2      l  3
12:    2      f  4
13:    2      i  5
14:    2      b  6
15:    2      n  7
16:    2      g  8
17:    2      l  9
18:    2      k 10
19:    3      f  1
20:    3      h  2
```

I can do this for each individual `time` with a join like below (for `time` = 2).

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(time == 1)
df2 <- df %>% filter(time == 2)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = 'id') %>% 
  select(-time.y) %>% 
  rename(status = status.x,
         prev_status = status.y,
         time = time.x)

   time status id prev_status
1     2      m  1           j
2     2      l  2           g
3     2      l  3           k
4     2      f  4           m
5     2      i  5           d
6     2      b  6           c
7     2      n  7           m
8     2      g  8           o
9     2      l  9        <NA>
10    2      k 10        <NA>
```

Is there a better way to do this, that would create `prev_status` for the entire data.frame? I'm open to `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions (as well as base R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` has a `lag()` function which makes this easy

```
df %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(prev_status=lag(status))
```

Comment: Didn't expect it to be so easy. Putting `data.table` solution here for future reference: `df[order(time)][, prev_status := shift(status), by = id]`

Comment: @Renu When you chain with `DT[i][...]` the reference to the original table is broken. If instead you do `df[order(time), prev_status := shift(status), by = id]`, then the new column will be added to the original table.